Geometry Nodes: Deleting instances on the ends of a curve
I have this nodes set up that creates instances of an object along a curve to make corrugated pipes that don't deform like the ones made with an array. It also uses the curve to make and interior pipe with smaller diameter to join the instances together
The problem is that it places instances at the very end points of the curve and in a lot of situations it'd be better if the ends where only the smaller diameter pipe inside.

Is it possible to somehow limit the points that are used to generate the instances? As in, tell it 'ignore X number of points at the beginning of the curve' and 'ignore Y number of points at the end of the curve'


Endpoint selection node > Boolean Math set to Not.

Investigate the Endpoint Selection and Delete Geometry nodes. You should be able to delete the instances at the end of your curve using just those nodes and a boolean math node.

Sorry but I don't know enough geometry nodes to even know what that means

you can use this node setup:

to get this:

each point has an index. You can use the domain size to know how much points exist. So by delete geometry you can delete points depending on the index. The rest is simple math.

Thanks you, much appreciated

you are welcome
